# How to prepare recursive reports based on a field value?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

I am preparing a SSRS report where a table in the body has to be generated by considering a field value in header part and should repeat the same for all values of that field. I have created a group in body and used the expression =First(Fields!Field.Value, "DataSet"). It is generating all the values in the table but value in the header part doesn't change.

I also tried creating a group in the table and using one of the value from the group in the header part. But it is not possible as we are restricted to use group variables inside the group but not in the header part of the report.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to picture what you are describing.   Maybe some screenshots would help?   Especially an illustration of what you have now, and what you want to have.

Comment: @TabAlleman I am using a stored procedure which gives restaurant name, owner and items in that restaurant. In the page header, we should show restaurant name and owner, it should display all the items of that restaurant in the table. When one restaurant is over a page break appears and have to repeat the same for next restuarant.

Comment: Sounds like you can use a Tablix with one row per restaurant and put a page break after each row.